# ads does not appear after adding my app id and unit id

Tags: javascript, android, admob

when I tested my app with Ad-mob test id it worked fine but after using my app id and unit id nothing appear, I spend a lot of time searching for a solution but did not find any, although I followed the trial [this Ad-mob official trial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) but still got nothing, also keep in mind that i changed my project name and followed some steps to achieve that but after i did that i get endless errors in my instrumentation (java file) and method.java files  and other java files in my project but they do not affect on my app building or running but i mentioned them anyway, maybe they have affect on my ads problem . so please if anyone can help I am new to java programming and app development......... this screen shots for ads code implementation

main activity ads implementations
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXufQ.png)

xml file ads implementations
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz6hM.png)

build.gradle
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjSsH.png)

build.gradle dependencies
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvgOx.png)

[instrumentation(java file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GamnK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUaaU.png)

[method.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbyu2.png)

.

Answer (score 1):

> You Have To Add Payment Details in Admob Account

Comment: i already did that but still the same problem  nothing happened

Comment: Check With admob test id

Comment: as i explained in my post i checked with admob test id and worked just fine but after using my app id and unit id nothing appear.

Comment: check your log cat

Answer (score -1):

How new is your account?  Sometimes it could take a few days for ads to appear.  Your location may play a role in ads not showing as well.

Comment: Not really an answer. Use comments for this.

Comment: Thanks.  New to using SA.